How can i call function on smart contract with infura and with metamask provider on iOS
I am trying to call the getString method from a contract on iOS. I tried using
https://github.com/Boilertalk/Web3.swift
https://github.com/web3swift-team/web3swift
When I tried to call the function using Infura as the Web3 provider, I got an error: contractNotDeployed
let web3 = Web3(rpcURL: "https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/57dfdd546d3543ae8673767e6180a5f1")
let abiString = "[{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"getString\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"payable\":false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"}]"
        let contractJsonABI = abiString.data(using: .utf8)!
let contractAddress = try? EthereumAddress("0xd05424D70fBE11651909c47d4773639272885195")
        let contract = try? web3.eth.Contract(json: contractJsonABI, abiKey: nil, address: contractAddress)
        
        
        firstly {
            (contract?["getString"]!().call())!
        }.done { outputs in
            print(outputs as Any)
        }.catch { error in
            print("blad")
            print(error)
        }

This is my ABI
[
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getString",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]

And the second problem is: How can I use the installed MetaMask on iOS as a provider instead of Infura?
